# Flutter -How to Pass variable from one dart class to another dart class

Tags: flutter

I just want to pass my int and bool values into another class in another dart file.
I am trying to pass values the method.

Comment: Do you want to change the color or action button or change the action button itself

Comment: Are you trying to implement multi select concept?

Comment: Yes.Multiselecting the Card and then do some operation

Comment: OK give me some time. I'll get back after i complete.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the idea...

Comment: Can you please share the current code which you have wrote?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new MainPage(),
    ));

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => new _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int count = 0;
  bool isMultiSelectStarted = false;

  void onMultiSelectStarted(int count, bool isMultiSelect) {
    print('Count: $count  isMultiSelectStarted: $isMultiSelect');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text('Go to SecondPage'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return new SecondPage(onMultiSelectStarted);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int count = 1;
  bool isMultiSelectStarted = true;

  final Function multiSelect;

  SecondPage(this.multiSelect);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text('Pass data to MainPage'),
        onPressed: () {
          widget.multiSelect(widget.count, widget.isMultiSelectStarted);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but since product is an object it should be like a.name not a['name'].  I hope this is the right way. Rest of yours is perfect I think.

Comment: I changed that. But I got an error on the product.sort((a,b) ..Error such as "The method 'sort' isn't defined for the class 'class name'.

Comment: sortProducts() {
 _products.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
}       seems to be working for me. I've tested it. I think you are trying to sort the getter field that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: Yeah you can use PopupMenuButton         new PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context) {
          new PopupMenuItem(child: new Text(''));
        })

Comment: You can also define the two variables in the main class itself and change those values in child rather than passing from child to parent

Comment: When you are accessing the constructor of child something like  `body: new Child(),` pass a callback with it like `void _rebuild() {
    setState(() {});
  }`  `body: new Child(_rebuild),`. In child  `Child(this.rebuild);`
  `final VoidCallback rebuild;`    `onTap() { int x = something;  bool y = something;  rebuild();`

Comment: Actually, I want to pass int x, bool y from one sample1.dart to sample2.dart.

Comment: Can you modify your question like somewhat related to this? Since providing full code in comments will not be useful for anyone, I can provide the complete answer.

Comment: Vinoth: I want to implement popup menu in bottom navigation bar.is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is.                                                                                                            
     new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (pos) {},
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return <PopupMenuEntry>[
                new PopupMenuItem(child: new Text('Option 1')),
                new PopupMenuItem(child: new Text('Option 2')),
                new PopupMenuItem(child: new Text('Option 3')),
              ];
            },
          ),
          title: new Container(),
        )