# How to call a method in another stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I am building a podcasting type app, so need to call the record, stop, and play functions in many places, I created the methods, but difficulty to call these methods in other places.

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;

void startRecord() //Need to call all of these method in coming stateful widgets         
void stopRecord() //
void pauseRecord()//
void resumeRecord()//
void play() //

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return MyApp();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),

      //more code is here 

Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: 40,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    startRecord();
                  }),
            ),
          ),



}



class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(


onPressed: () {
startRecord()

// need to call the method here. 

}

Pressed: () {
    stopRecord()

// need to call the method here. 

}

Pressed: () {
    play()

// need to call the method here. 

}

),
}
```

Need to call all the methods from a first stateful widget for bottom stateful widgets

also, need to call these methods for other classes when code progress

both stateful widgets are in the main.dart. I could not call the method from the first class for the second stateful widget

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. and few questions is your method ```startRecord``` outside the ```_MyAppState``` Class? and is the classes on different ```Dart``` files? And Can you share the whole code?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733840/trigger-a-function-from-a-widget-to-a-state-object

Comment: @AdithyaShetty no  it is inside the MyAppState

Comment: @AdithyaShetty it is on the same main.dart file

Comment: @Derek Checked that but did not understand much, I am a beginner in Flutter

Comment: Where is `MyHomePage` used? Is it the home of `MyApp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a rocket science, just a simple line of code, and you are done.

What you have to do, is to just call the `MyHomePage()` and let it accept the `startRecording()` to be used inside the Widget

**1. Passing the data from MyApp() to MyHomePage()**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // here you pass the your function
      home: MyHomePage(onPressed: startRecording)
    );
  }
```

**2. Receiving the data in MyHomePage()**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // let it accept a function type onPressed argument
  final Function onPressed;
  
  // constructor
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.onPressed}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

    // simply call the onPressed which received your startRecording() from MyApp
    onPressed: () => widget.onPressed()
}
```

Comment: It should be `onPressed: startRecording` instead of `onPressed: startRecording()`.

Comment: Oh yes, I have mistakenly done that, Thanks for pointing out @Mobina :)

Comment: @Alok I already created with home. sharing more code, please check

Answer (score 1):

You can get the state of a parent widget using the `BuildContext` of the child widget like so:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
  
  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;
  
  void startRecord() {
    print('Hello');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyApp.of(context).startRecord();
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define that function outside the class as a stand-alone function like this But if you want to call from inside the class. Heres the code.

inside a different class as a static function:

```
onPressed: () {
          _MyAppState().startRecord(); //call using the class name.
        }
```

Like this inside your `onpressed Statement`.

Should work.

Or else what you can do is define the function outside the class. Then use it where ever you want. Like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}


void startRecord(){
   .
   .
   .
}           /// Like here outside the class

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(.....



}



class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(


onPressed: () {
 startRecord();       // call Here as follows.
 }),
}
```